# Standard error calculation of intercept in logarithmic line equation?

Tags: regression, python, standard-error, logarithm

I have a line equation log(y) = mlog(x) + log(c) for which I have plotted log(x) vs log(y) scatter plot using the given x and y values then performed linear regression to get best fit line. Using which I have calculated m and c values. But I need standard error of c such that I can write in form of c +- {delta}c. How should I get this error component

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+standard+error+formula+answers%3A1 is a search for related answers.  They show you formulas for the standard error of $\log(\hat c).$ You can apply them (using the delta method or maximum likelihood) to convert that into a standard error for $\hat c$ -- but wouldn't it make better sense to express the error in $\hat c$ *multiplicatively* rather than additively?